# Get object values from string variable

Tags: php

I was googling and reading the manual, but couldn't find an answer.

Ie, have an array of strings like this:

```
$a = ['book->name', 'book->id'];
```

Now I need to get those values from `shelf` object. Normaly I would just ask:

```
$bookName = $shelf->book->name;
$bookId = $shelf->book->id;
```

But how do I read with the 2nd part beeing a string?

If I try `$shelf->{$a[0]}` I get `Undefined property: stdClass::$book->name in...`.

What is the way to solve this?

*PS: I know I can try eval, but would really like not to.*

Comment: No, you can't do this. Also, your objects are leaking encapsulation.

Comment: have you tried $shelf->$a[0] maybe this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by splitting the string:

```
$a = ['book->name', 'book->id'];

$parts = explode('->', $a[0]);
$bookName = $shelf->{$parts[0]}->{$parts[1]};

$parts = explode('->', $a[1]);
$bookId = $shelf->{$parts[0]}->{$parts[1]};
```

This assumes you know how deeply nested your properties are going to be. I'd probably wrap this in a function to be able to handle an unknown number of properties:

```
function getPropertyByString($object, $properties) {
    $parts = explode('->', $properties);
    $value = $object;

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (!property_exists($value, $part)) {
            throw new OutOfBoundsException('Object does not contain a property called "' . $part . '"');
        }

        $value = $value->$part;
    }

    return $value;
}

$bookName = getPropertyByString($shelf, $a[0]);
$bookId = getPropertyByString($shelf, $a[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was my second option after `eval`, that I also ended up doing. Thought there might be a oneliner.